# Search for a button by its HTML Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

I am writing Coded UI Test's for a web app. I am having problems such as I record actions using the test builder, however sometimes the button that is clicked has different information each time I run the test and as result VS can't find the button.

The html code never changes so what I want to do is **find the button by its html code and click it that way**.

For example on Google the path to the search button is

```
<button id="gbqfba" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" class="gbqfba"><span id="gbqfsa">Google Search</span></button>
```

How can I click this button using the code above or Alternativly using the XPath

```
//*[@id="gbqfba"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adjust the Search Properties and Filter Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('button span').each(function(){
If($(this).html() == "Google Search")
{
   $(this).parent('button').click();
}
});
```

Comment: Sry maybe I wasn't 100% clear, this is Visual Studio Coded ui tests, no javascript

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, If you go to the UIMap.uitest file and click the method you have the problem with you can change the **filter properties** and the **search properties** to remove parts that are failing your test.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
BrowserWindow.ExecuteScript("$('#gbqfba').click();");
```